# Unicode string from CSV: replace \xHex symbols with unicode values

Tags: ruby, string, unicode, csv

I read some Unicode data from a CSV file using standard Ruby 1.9 csv library like this:

```
def read_csv(file_name, value)
    CSV.foreach(file_name) do |row|
      if row[0] == value
        return row[1]
      end
    end
end
```

And I get a string, the Unicode symbols looks okay in debug.

```
Invitación
```

But if I put it (or compare with another string) it looks like this:

```
Invitaci\xC3\xB3n
```

How to convert those hex symbols to values? Or maybe I read this CSV file wrong somehow?

Comment: Bash command echo $LC_ALL
retruns nothing

Comment: Thanks, but i found another solution, without using enviroment variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found this myself.
Just change line

```
CSV.foreach(file_name) do |row|
```

on line

```
CSV.foreach(file_name, encoding: "UTF-8") do |row|
```

and this work flawless